# how do I enter start point in shortest path algorithm in QGIS 3.0.1?

Tags: algorithm, qgis-3, shortest-path

Are the x and y values displayed by the Vertex Editor (bottom left of image) not the same as the x and y values in my *TestNetwork* layer required by the Shortest path algorithm?

[image: Shortest Path Error]

Comment: Remove leading and trailing parentheses in both "Start point" and "End point"

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz Thanks!  I'm embarrassed that I didn't think to try that!

Comment: Parentheses in parameter's name make everybody think that they should be used.

Comment: Exactly...they are shown in the GUI so I thought that they were needed.

Comment: Good point - fixed in https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/6772